# Refresh em um View a partir de um ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

Equipe, tenho uma dúvida.
Estou desenvolvendo uma tela de detalhes de um pedido, onde existe um botão utilizado para Assumir esse pedido.

Para ficar mais claro, essa tela de detalhes de comporta de formas diferentes para diferentes status:

```
using CoreGraphics;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.iOS.Views;
using UIKit;
using Valdemar.Core.ViewModels;

namespace Valdemar.IOs
{
    public sealed partial class DetailView : MvxViewController<DetailViewModel>
    {
        private bool _constructed;

        public DetailView() : base("DetailView", null)
        {
            ViewDidLoad();
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            if (ViewModel == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var close = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.System);
            close.Frame = new CGRect(8, 35, 50, 20);
            close.SetTitle("Voltar", UIControlState.Normal);
            Add(close);

            /*
             * Binding
             */
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<DetailView, Core.ViewModels.DetailViewModel>();

            set.Bind(lblWhat).To(vm => vm.Item.itemsDes);
            set.Bind(lblHowMuch).To(vm => vm.Item.valueDes);
            set.Bind(lblWhen).To(vm => vm.Item.limitTime);
            set.Bind(lblStatus).To(vm => vm.Item.status);
            set.Bind(lblUser).To(vm => vm.Item.usersTOByIdClientUser.personsTO.namePerson);
            //set.Bind(lblAdress).To(vm => vm.Item.usersTOByIdClientUser);
            set.Bind(lblResponsible).To(vm => vm.Item.valdecoOwner);
            set.Bind(lblConfirmed).To(vm => vm.Item.confirmed);
            set.Bind(lblCreated).To(vm => vm.Item.created);
            set.Bind(close).To(vm => vm.CloseCommand);
            set.Bind(close).For("Clicked").To(vm => vm.CloseCommand);

            if (lblStatus.Text == "A")
            {
                btnAction.SetTitle("Assumir Pedido!", UIControlState.Normal);
                set.Bind(btnAction).To(vm => vm.BtnAssumeCommand);
                lblStatus.Hidden = true;
                lblConfirmation.Hidden = true;
                lblResponsible.Hidden = true;
            }
            else if (lblStatus.Text == "V")
            {
                set.Bind(lblStatus).To(vm => vm.V);
                btnAction.SetTitle("Entreguei!", UIControlState.Normal);
                set.Bind(btnAction).To(vm => vm.BtnDeliverCommand);
                lblConfirmation.Hidden = true;
            }
            else if (lblStatus.Text == "E")
            {
                set.Bind(lblStatus).To(vm => vm.E);
                lblConfirmation.Hidden = false;
                btnAction.Hidden = true;
            }
            else if (lblStatus.Text == "C")
            {
                lblConfirmation.Hidden = true;
                btnAction.Hidden = true;
                lblConfirmed.Hidden = false;
                set.Bind(lblStatus).To(vm => vm.C);
            }

            set.Apply();
        }
    }
}
```

Quando disparo o comando do botão, eu terei que alterar o status do meu pedido, e consequentemente, esconder o botão de "Assumir".

```
private async Task<bool> assumeOrder()
{
    var response = await orderService.assumeResp(getOrder());

    if (response == null)
    {
        messageService.showMessage("Pedido " + Item.id + " assumido com sucesso!");

        orderService.deleteAvailableOrder(Item);

        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Item);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Qual a melhor forma de fazer, principalmente que o botão "desapareça"?
Estou tentando através do RaisePropertyChanged(() => Item), ele atualiza as propriedades, mas não acessa novamente o View para alterá-lo de acordo com o seu novo Status.

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, via código não sei como ficaria mas com `xaml` teria que definir a propriedade `IsVisible="{Binding OcultarBotao, Mode=TwoWay}"`para ocultar um botão.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, ainda não precisei fazer algo do tipo para Xamarin.iOs especificamente e se eu entendi você quer que o botão esteja ativo ou não de acordo com a validação do mesmo, certo ? se for isso não seria o caso de você atribuir um CanExecute no BtnAssumeCommand ?

Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
public ICommand DeleteItemCommand{
get { 
    return m_DeleteItemCommand ?? (m_DeleteItemCommand = new MvxCommand<int>(ExecDeleteItem,CanExecDeleteItem)); 
}}

public void ExecDeleteItem(int index){
Mvx.Trace($"Deleting item at {index}");}


public bool CanExecDeleteItem(int index){Mvx.Trace($"Checking removal at {index}");return index > 0;}
```

Veja exemplo completo [aqui](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/tag/xamarin-ios/).

Estou te passando essa informação baseado no que já fiz em Xamarin.Forms, como disse ainda não fiz algo do tipo no iOs, mas espero ter ajudado.

OBS. O código do exemplo não entrava como "Amostra de código" quando estava identado, por isso está dessa forma.

Comment: Brian, os links quebram e podem deixar a resposta aqui inutilizável. A intenção aqui é termos o conteúdo dentro do próprio site.